# how to continuously check for a request from server in android?

Tags: java, php, android, service

I want to make a app which can respond to server requests. For example, if I press a button in the browser of my PC to take a screenshot of my phone then my app will respond back with the screenshot. I think I need to make a service which will always check for a request from server. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't go that way, or you'll consume all the phone battery. I think your best chance is to have a push-notification type of system, for instance [GCM](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-get-started-with-push-notifications-on-android--cms-25870).

Comment: You can use push notifications for this purpose
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: You need to implement any real-time mechanism such as push notification using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) or real-time connection between server and client using [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that with google's firebase service, it's for free.

Comment: this should be in comments

Comment: Sorry im new using the app, I actually wanted to type a comment

Answer (score 0):

Create a service which will request to a server after specific time interval like 5 mins or 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

There are three major things you need to do.

- Server that fires push to client(Android Device) on specific action from user.
- Client(Android Device) which receives push and do task according to
  push message and send acknowledgement to server.
- Servers reads
  acknowledgement from the client and update user for task done/undone.